# Publishing packages marked as private to verdaccio

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, devops, verdaccio

Is it possible to publish packages marked as private to Verdaccio without removing `private:true` from `package.json`?

The NPM documentation says that we can also use `publishConfig` to ensure that a package is only published to a specific directory, but there are not examples how to go about configuring it:

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#private

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I replaced `private:true` with:

```
  "publishConfig":{
    "access": "restricted",
    "registry":"http://localhost:4873"
  },
```

Note that the package has to be scoped, so I added the `@fireflysemantics` scope:

```
  "name": "@fireflysemantics/package-name"
```